# Pointing to an object of a UserControl instance

Tags: c#, winforms

My program contains an empty TabControl. This can be populated by the user that, through an action, can add to the TabControl an instance of a custom UserControl I have defined:

```
myUserControl newInstance;
newInstance = new myUserControl();
myTabControl.TabPages.Add(newInstance);
```

This object `myUserControl` is not just a simple empty `TabPage`, but it's containing some other objects such as `textboxes`, `comboboxes` and `labels`.

How can I point, for example, to the first textbox of this new page to change its text? I was thinking about this:

```
myTabControl.SelectedTab.textbox1.Text = "change the text";
```

But it does not work, I cannot compile because of the following error (that I pretty much understand):

```
'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' does not contain a definition for 'textbox1' and no extension method 'textbox1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I point to the textbox that should be into the instance of `myUserControl` that I have added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an instance or with events. Here's an example with an instance.

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
public static myUserControl Instance {get; set;}

public myUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Instance = this;
}

public string textBoxText
{
    get { return textbox1.text; }
    set { textbox1.text = value; }
}
```

}

Set the texbox text in this way.

```
   myUserControl.Instance.textBoxText="your text";
```

Comment: Hi @Sybren, I have a problem with your method. Using `Instance` works very fine but with the last instance only. How can I manage if I need to retrieve previous instances of the class (for example to modify the text of a `myUserControl` instance that I have made before the last one)?

Comment: I have opened a new thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340904/using-previous-instances-of-a-usercontrol), in case you'd like to answer.